# My Binance parser doesnt work.How to fix it?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://p2p.binance.com/ru/trade/all-payments/USDT?fiat=BYN'

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

def parser(url):
    list = []
    link = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    page = bs(link.content, 'html.parser')
    for i in page.find_all('div', class_="css-1m1f8hn"):
        list.append(i.text)
    return list


print(parser(url))
```

Im trying to write a binance p2p page parser, but it returns an empty list. As I can guess, find_all method doesnt see any divs with this class

Comment: That page uses javascript.  But `requests` does not understand javascript.  You will have to use some other way to fetch the page content.

Answer (score 0):

The data is loaded from external URL in Json form. You can use `requests` module to simulate this call:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

api = 'https://p2p.binance.com/bapi/c2c/v2/friendly/c2c/adv/search'

payload = {
    "asset": "USDT",
    "countries": [],
    "fiat": "EUR",
    "page": 1,  # <-- increase page here
    "payTypes": [],
    "proMerchantAds": False,
    "publisherType": None,
    "rows": 10,
    "tradeType": "BUY"
}

data = requests.post(api, json=payload).json()

all_data = []
for d in data['data']:
    all_data.append({'name': d['advertiser']['nickName'], 'price': d['adv']['price']})

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
             name  price
0           BTC99  0.914
1         BabayGG  0.915
2            YMRA  0.915
3           nikdo  0.915
4         Rayxard  0.915
5        FUNTER93  0.916
6  MorrisonTrades  0.916
7      Treader_09  0.916
8          KatPay  0.916
9   cambio_crypto  0.917
```